# creating array from an array with value manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text area where coworkers input file names with no extensions, followed by a return.  my code takes this input list and creates an array called `$list`.  it will then take that array and create an updated array called `$genList` with extra file names like this:

```
$fileString = $_POST['fileList'];
$unique = $_POST['unique'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$generateArray = $_POST['generateArray'];

$list = explode("\r\n",$fileString);

if ($generateArray == "yes") {
    if ($size == "5x7inimpos") {
        $genList = array();
        foreach($list as $element) {
            array_push($genList, $element . "_f", $element . "_b", $element . "_i");   
        }
    }           
    $list = array();
    $list = $genList;           
}
```

so as it stands, if a worker inputs some file names like so:

```
HOL_12_001_00
HOL_12_002_00
HOL_12_003_00
```

it will eventually get converted as an array with the extensions on the end of the file name like this:

```
$list = array(HOL_12_001_00_f, HOL_12_001_00_b, HOL_12_001_00_i, HOL_12_002_00_f, HOL_12_002_00_b, HOL_12_002_00_i, HOL_12_003_00_f, HOL_12_003_00_b, HOL_12_003_00_i);
```

but what i really need to do is have the final array (with the `_f`, `_b`, `_i`) inside of the file name like this:

```
$list = array(HOL_12_f_001_00, HOL_12_b_001_00, HOL_12_i_001_00, HOL_12_f_002_00, HOL_12_b_002_00, HOL_12_i_002_00, HOL_12_f_003_00, HOL_12_b_003_00, HOL_12_i_003_00);
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: is there fix naming convention of filenames ? or file names can be anyname ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your following code:

```
foreach($list as $element) {
    array_push($genList, $element . "_f", $element . "_b", $element . "_i");   
}
```

for this one:

```
$letter = array('f','b','i');
foreach($list as $element) {
    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
        $arr = explode('_', $element);
        $arr[1] .= '_' . $letter[$i];
        $genList[] = implode('_', $arr);
    }
}
```

that will generate the array in the way you described.

Comment: thanks! it does work, but i'm not understanding how/where you specified to enter the letters in the correct spot.  can you explain?

Comment: the trick is the explode() and implode() functions, read about them on http://www.php.net